# Ошибка «Не найденно имя файла или сборки...» при компиляции

Tags: c#, компиляция

Почему после компиляции проекта и последующего запуска получаю ошибку:

"Не найденно имя файла или сборки «`System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Capture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C56193E089`» либо одна из их зависимостей."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте, подключена ли у вас или нет сборка `System.Windows.Forms` в проект: для этого раскройте элемент References в проекте. Если ее там нет, правой клавишей -> `Add Reference`, и там в диалоге выберите нужную сборку.